# Showing DialogFragment from an ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

Is it possible to show a `FragmentDialog` when a tab is selected in the `ActionBar`?

The `onTabSelected()` method happens inside a transaction that is commited after the execution of the method finishes. However, the `show()` method in `DialogFragment` does also happen in a transaction automatically, so if you try to show the dialog when the tab is selected you get  a `RuntimeException` because the transaction gets commited twice.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore the supplied `FragmentTransaction`.

For example, you need to do this if you are using the Android Compatibility Library (ACL), because the `FragmentTransaction` you get from the action bar is an Android 3.0 `FragmentTransaction`, not an ACL `FragmentTransaction`. So, you ignore the passed-in one and use your own.

Similarly, I would expect that you can ignore the `FragmentTransaction` and display a `DialogFragment` yourself without problems.

Whether the UX will make any sense is another problem. When the user accepts the dialog the tab shows... nothing?

Comment: The idea is to show some sort of submenu on the top of the content area (just below the action bar) when a tab is selected. This submenu contains filtering options that will replace the content area with actual content upon selection.

Comment: @mgv: ::shrug:: Still sounds odd to me. The submenu seems fine; using a transient UI element like a dialog does not. The user taps a tab, chooses an item from the submenu, and... now can't choose anything else from the submenu, because it's gone. Why not use "list" navigation instead of tabs, and render the rows in the `Spinner` to suggest your menu hierarchy?

Comment: It's true, it sounds rather odd. I have been asked to do it this way, but I think I will fight for my right to party and follow your advice. P.S: Ignoring the FragmentTransaction worked, so your answer was right.